# Dumping entity in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I am using Spring Boot with Kotlin, and want to dump an entity to the browser.

**Entities.kt:**

```
@Entity
class Person(
    var name: String,
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) var id: Long? = null
)

@Entity
class Cat(
    var name: String,
    @ManyToOne var ownedBy: Person,
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) var id: Long? = null
)
```

**HtmlController.kt:**

```
@Controller
class HtmlController(private val repository: CatRepository) {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun index(model: Model): String {
        model["cats"] = repository.findAll()
        return "index"
    }
}
```

In my `index` template I am able to loop through the `cat`s with `{#cats}{/cats}`, but I want to dump the whole lot out (e.g. to see what relationships are available). Is that possible? I tried modifying the controller above to `return respository.findAll().toString()` but that gives me the error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When returning a `String` from a `Controller`, `Spring MVC` will assume that you are pointing to a view-file. So it will look for a file in some configured folder, where the file name is the string-representation of a list of `Cat`s. This, of course, does not exist, and you get a 404.

The simplest way of doing this would be to create a "REST-style" endpoint, and return the data as a fitting data format, for instance json. My example is with Java, but you could transform to Kotlin:

```
@RestController
public class CatRestController {

    @Autowired
    private CatRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/cats", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Cat> getAllCats() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Spring Boot should automatically convert the list to json. The method might work if moved to your existing Spring MVC controller, but I haven't tested. I have an example from a regular Spring MVC project (not Spring Boot), and the method signature looks something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/cats.json")
public @ResponseBody List<Cat> getCats() {
```

Comment: Another tip: Use a browser-plugin that converts json to pretty-printed json :)